# Object oriented programming in python, append (3 dimensional array elements) to a list

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, append

```
import numpy as np
""" A project on beamtracer """
class beam:
    def __init__(self,x = np.array([1,2,3]),v = np.array([2,3,4])):
        self.x = np.array(x)
        self.v = np.array(v)
        self.X = [self.x]
        self.V = [self.v]
        self.z = [(self.X,self.V)]


    def p(self):
        return self.x
    def k(self):
        return self.v
    def append(self,(self.x,self.v)):
        return self.z(append(self.x,self.v))
    def coll(self):
        return self.z
```

I was trying to create a beamtracer, so that I can store the 3dimensional position, as well as 3dimensional direction vector at each point, I want self.z to be a list that I can append a 2 elements tuple ( self.x,self.v ) at a time where x and v are 3d arrays
Lastly, I wanted to return all the pairs of points I had stored before, I can't really see what my codes are doing wrong. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
def append(self,(self.x,self.v)):
    return self.z(append(self.x,self.v))
```

`self.x` does not make sense until `self` has a value, which is not the case when the `append` definition is parsed.

Also, `self.z(append...)` should be `self.z.append`.
You could use

```
def append(self, x, v):
    return self.z.append([x, v])
```

instead.

---

Warning: you might want to reconsider using lots of small NumPy arrays. The overall performance of such  code tends to be disappointing (no better and sometimes worse than if you had just used Python lists or tuples).

To get good performance out of NumPy, you generally want to try to arrange your calculation to use the fewest number of NumPy function calls possible (ideally with no Python loops) and apply those function calls to a single large array, rather than lots of function calls on lots of small arrays.